# Color component in svelte

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component

I am learning svelte and was wondering if there is an error color handler in svelte if I try to put anything than a color as an input?

```js
const submitHandler = (e) => {
    valid = true;
    if(e.color != couleur){
        valid = false;
    } 
    else {
        color = e.target.value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you are looking for the html color input: https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_input_type_color.asp

Comment: you can use `class:` [directive](https://svelte.dev/docs#class_name)

Answer (score 0):

Although it's not usually great UX to ask for specific color data and not provide a color picker, it is possible and maybe you have a decent reason.

You can use RegEx to check if the user provided a valid color code (assuming you're referring to hex). [Here](https://www.regextester.com/93840)'s an expression that will do the validation for you, just create a RegExp object with it: `const regex = new RegExp('^#([A-Fa-f0-9]{6}|[A-Fa-f0-9]{3})$')`

And check if the value provided by the user passes the test `regex.test(yourValue)` or if you're just asking for the hexcode and not the `#` before it then `regex.test('#' + yourValue)`. Also no need to do `e.target.value` since you can just bind the input to a variable and use that to test.

Here's a [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/b35844edceb54834a8443de895868f8d?version=3.37.0) showing one possible way of doing this

It's not quite clear what your aim is for this and why you would want to check for the validity of the input on submit, but it might be better for your users if you use a reactive declaration to check for validity as shown in this [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/a15ac8ac33c542f8b4857575f703a8d0?version=3.37.0).

Or only check the validity on:blur like in this [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/50e956424e1248b4b8827f66ab6069e9?version=3.37.0).